# Multiple clicks on same element removes classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the problem that I wanted to add and remove classes on clicking an element. But if I click the same element twice, the added classes will be removed. I don't really get whats the problem here.

```
$('#01').click( function() {    
    $(".d1").removeClass("show-forms");
    $(".d2").removeClass("show-forms");
    $(".pick-notice").toggleClass("hide-forms");
    $(".d0").removeClass( "hide-forms" );
    $(".d0").toggleClass("show-forms");
} );
```

Also is there a way to use the same function for more elements, something like this:

```
$('#01, #02, #03').click( function() {...
```

I tried this but it didnt worked

```
$('#01', '#02', '#03').click( function() {...
```

Comment: where are you adding the classes

Comment: and you are using toggleClass offcourse it will toggle the class that you have added

Comment: Those classes will be added to a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To assign the same function to multiple selectors your first code should work (see here for reference: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$('#01, #02, #03').click( function() {} );
```

It's not overly clear from your example where you are adding the classes, I think you are probably looking to use addClass (https://api.jquery.com/addClass/) as opposed to toggleClass (https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). addClass adds the class to the selected element. Whereas toggleClass will add the class to the selected element if it doesn't already have the class, and if it does have the class it will remove it. So that could be why the second time you click it removes the class?

Try the following:

```
$('#01').click( function() {    
    $(".d1").removeClass("show-forms");
    $(".d2").removeClass("show-forms");
    $(".pick-notice").addClass("hide-forms");
    $(".d0").removeClass( "hide-forms" );
    $(".d0").addClass("show-forms");
} );
```

Or if you want multiple selectors:

```
$('#01, #02, #03').click( function() {    
    $(".d1").removeClass("show-forms");
    $(".d2").removeClass("show-forms");
    $(".pick-notice").addClass("hide-forms");
    $(".d0").removeClass( "hide-forms" );
    $(".d0").addClass("show-forms");
} );
```

Comment: The addClass part helped with one problem. But there is still one problem: When the div with the class .d0 already has the class .show-forms and I click again on the element #01, the class .show-forms will be deleted.

Comment: Did you change that from toggleClass to addClass also? Mind sharing what you have currently? :)

Comment: My bad. Now it works perfectly. It was cached in the browser... THANKS!

Comment: Brilliant, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for selecting muntiple class at a time :

```
$("#01, #02, #03").click( function() {...});
```

This will work on each Id

Comment: you can update the code at jsbin and provide the link so that we can see that whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the first part of your question but for the second part of your question:

I think it'd be a much better solution to make it a class

so `01,02,03` are all a certain class (i.e. `.clickable`)

with this you can just `$(.clickable).click(function(){`